# Jquery Tools Scrollable with Autorotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollable

who can help me to make this gallery to autorotate?

Jquery Tools Scrollable

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

Thanks a lot!

Vic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do it yourself with a timer, something like this should do it:

```
function auto_next() {
    $('#scroller').data('scrollable').next();
    setTimeout(auto_next, 1000); // 1000 == one second
}
auto_next();
```

You could also use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) but then you'd run the risk of your timed events overrunning each other.

References:

- [jQuery Tools API](http://flowplayer.org/tools/documentation/scripting.html)
- [Scrollable API](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html#api)
- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)